# Where do you put an Apostrophe in this sentence

Tags: apostrophe

This position will play a key role in the Universities fundraising strategies.

Comment: Where would you think?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about the fundraising strategies of Universities, the apostrophe will come after the word *Universities*. See below:

This position will play a key role in the Universities' fundraising strategies.

The easy way to remember the use of apostrophe is to identify possession, i.e. a person / thing that owns or is related to something. As in the above example, the fundraising strategies belong to the Universities.

Also, had you been only talking about one University - the placement of apostrophe would have changed. See below:

This position will play a key role in the University's fundraising strategies.

- For singular nouns, you put an apostrophe first and then the *'s'* *(University's fundraising strategies)*
- For plural nouns, you put an *'s'* first and then an apostrophe *(Universities' fundraising strategies)*
- For plural not ending with an s, you put an apostrophe first and then the
  *'s'* *(Children's play area)*